# QuickBooks Online SDK Payment Credit Card Issue

Tags: c#, sdk, payment, quickbooks

I am trying to submit a Credit Card Payment using the QuickBooks Online SDK, but when I run my code I get the following error:

> Raw Credit Card Number not supported. Tokenized Credit Card Number
>   Required

Here is what I have. Can anyone explain how I can tokenize the card number using sdk before using it in this manner?

```
public Payment PaymentCreditCard(Order order, ServiceContext qboContextoAuth)
{
    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.TxnDate = Convert.ToDateTime(order.DateCreated);
    payment.TxnDateSpecified = true;
    Account depositAccount = Helper.FindOrAddAccount(qboContextoAuth, AccountTypeEnum.Bank, AccountClassificationEnum.Asset);
    payment.DepositToAccountRef = new ReferenceType()
    {
        name = depositAccount.Name,
        Value = depositAccount.Id
    };
    PaymentMethod paymentMethod = Helper.FindOrAdd<PaymentMethod>(qboContextoAuth, new PaymentMethod());
    payment.PaymentMethodRef = new ReferenceType()
    {
        name = paymentMethod.Name,
        Value = paymentMethod.Id
    };
    Customer customer = Helper.FindOrAdd<Customer>(qboContextoAuth, new Customer());
    payment.CustomerRef = new ReferenceType()
    {
        name = customer.DisplayName,
        Value = customer.Id
    };

    payment.PaymentType = PaymentTypeEnum.CreditCard;

    CreditCardPayment creditCardPayment = new CreditCardPayment();
    CreditChargeInfo creditChargeInfo = new CreditChargeInfo();
    creditChargeInfo.BillAddrStreet = order.BillingAddress;
    creditChargeInfo.CcExpiryMonth = Convert.ToInt32(order.CCExpMonth); 
    creditChargeInfo.CcExpiryMonthSpecified = true;
    creditChargeInfo.CcExpiryYear = Convert.ToInt32(order.CCExpYear);
    creditChargeInfo.CcExpiryYearSpecified = true;
    creditChargeInfo.CCTxnMode = CCTxnModeEnum.CardNotPresent;
    creditChargeInfo.CCTxnModeSpecified = true;
    creditChargeInfo.CCTxnType = CCTxnTypeEnum.Charge;
    creditChargeInfo.CCTxnTypeSpecified = true;
    //reditChargeInfo.CommercialCardCode = "Cardcode" + Helper.GetGuid().Substring(0, 5);
    creditChargeInfo.NameOnAcct = order.BillingName;
    creditChargeInfo.Number = order.CCNum;
    creditChargeInfo.PostalCode = order.BillingZip; 
    creditCardPayment.CreditChargeInfo = creditChargeInfo;

    payment.AnyIntuitObject = creditCardPayment;
    payment.TotalAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(order.TotalAmount);
    payment.TotalAmtSpecified = true;
    payment.UnappliedAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(order.TotalAmount);
    payment.UnappliedAmtSpecified = true;

    //Adding the Payment
    Payment added = Helper.Add<Payment>(qboContextoAuth, payment);

    return added;
}
```

From what I have gathered from the raw API, here is what I need:

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/tokens

But I don't seem to be able to find such functionality in the SDK. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: So after going back and forth a few times with their support team, they pointed me to a basic REST call example in the following GIT repository: 

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-Dotnet_Payments/blob/master/OAuth2-Dotnet_Payments/OAuth2-Dotnet_Payments/Default.aspx.cs

This however does NOT use the SDK, so now I am trying to see if the SDK supports this functionality or not.

Comment: I just got confirmation that their SDK as of today 03/14/19 does NOT have a way to generate a Payment Card Token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem as of today (03/14/19):

```c#
public string getCardToken()
{
    string cardToken="";
    JObject jsonDecodedResponse;
    string cardTokenJson = "";
    string cardTokenEndpoint = "quickbooks/v4/payments/tokens";
    string uri= paymentsBaseUrl + cardTokenEndpoint;

    string cardTokenRequestBody = "{\"card\":{\"expYear\":\"2020\",\"expMonth\":\"02\",\"address\":{\"region\":\"CA\",\"postalCode\":\"94086\",\"streetAddress\":\"1130 Kifer Rd\",\"country\":\"US\",\"city\":\"Sunnyvale\"},\"name\":\"emulate=0\",\"cvc\":\"123\",\"number\":\"4111111111111111\"}}";

    // send the request (token api call does not requires Authorization header, rest all payments call do)
    HttpWebRequest cardTokenRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    cardTokenRequest.Method = "POST";           
    cardTokenRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    cardTokenRequest.Headers.Add("Request-Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());//assign guid

    byte[] _byteVersion = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cardTokenRequestBody);
    cardTokenRequest.ContentLength = _byteVersion.Length;
    Stream stream = cardTokenRequest.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(_byteVersion, 0, _byteVersion.Length);
    stream.Close();

    // get the response
    HttpWebResponse cardTokenResponse = (HttpWebResponse)cardTokenRequest.GetResponse();
    using (Stream data = cardTokenResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        cardTokenJson= new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
        jsonDecodedResponse = JObject.Parse(cardTokenJson);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonDecodedResponse.TryGetString("value")))
        {
            cardToken = jsonDecodedResponse["value"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return cardToken;
}
```

They may add an SDK option to do the same some day, but it's not available as of today!